# When i teleport somewhere in my game my client crashes

Tags: java

When i teleport somewhere my client keeps crashing i don't know where the error is coming from. If the error isn't in the stream.java file where would it. I've been stuck on this for 2 days.
Error code

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at net.arrav.client.Stream.method422(Stream.java:225)
        at net.arrav.client.ObjectManager.method189(ObjectManager.java:1289)
        at net.arrav.client.Client.method54(Client.java:4011)
        at net.arrav.client.Client.loadingStages(Client.java:3978)
        at net.arrav.client.Client.method22(Client.java:1264)
        at net.arrav.client.Client.method54(Client.java:4021)
        at net.arrav.client.Client.loadingStages(Client.java:3978)
        at net.arrav.client.Client.mainGameProcessor(Client.java:4306)
        at net.arrav.client.Client.processGameLoop(Client.java:3469)
        at net.arrav.client.RSApplet.run(RSApplet.java:132)
        at net.arrav.client.Client.run(Client.java:6010)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

stream.java

```
package net.arrav.client;
import java.math.BigInteger;


public final class Stream extends NodeSub {

    public static Stream create() {
        synchronized(nodeList) {
            Stream stream = null;
            if(anInt1412 > 0) {
                anInt1412--;
                stream = (Stream) nodeList.popHead();
            }
            if(stream != null) {
                stream.currentOffset = 0;
                return stream;
            }
        }
        Stream stream_1 = new Stream();
        stream_1.currentOffset = 0;
        stream_1.buffer = new byte[250000];
        return stream_1;
    }


    private Stream() {
    }

    public int readShort2() {
        currentOffset += 2;
        int i = ((buffer[currentOffset - 2] & 0xff) << 8) + (buffer[currentOffset - 1] & 0xff);
        if(i  > 60000)
        i = -65535+i;
        return i;
    }

public Stream(byte abyte0[]) {
        buffer = abyte0;
            currentOffset = 0;
    }

    public void writeByte(int i)
    {
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)i;
    }

    public void createFrame(int i) {
        //System.out.println("Frame: " + i);
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(i + encryption.getNextKey());
    }

    public void writeWordBigEndian(int i) {
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)i;
    }

    public String readNewString()
    {
    int i = currentOffset;
    while(buffer[currentOffset++] != 0) ;
    return new String(buffer, i, currentOffset - i - 1);
    }

    public int readUSmart2()
    {
    int baseVal = 0;
    int lastVal = 0;
    while ((lastVal = method422()) == 32767) {
        baseVal += 32767;
    }
    return baseVal + lastVal;
    }

    public void writeWord(int i) {
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(i >> 8);
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)i;
    }

    public void method400(int i) {
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)i;
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(i >> 8);
    }

    public void writeDWordBigEndian(int i) {
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(i >> 16);
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(i >> 8);
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)i;
    }

    public void writeDWord(int i) {
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(i >> 24);
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(i >> 16);
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(i >> 8);
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)i;
    }

    public void method403(int j) {
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)j;
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(j >> 8);
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(j >> 16);
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(j >> 24);
    }

    public void writeQWord(long l) {
        try {
            buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(int)(l >> 56);
            buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(int)(l >> 48);
            buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(int)(l >> 40);
            buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(int)(l >> 32);
            buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(int)(l >> 24);
            buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(int)(l >> 16);
            buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(int)(l >> 8);
            buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(int)l;
        } catch(RuntimeException runtimeexception) {
            SignLink.reporterror("14395, " + 5 + ", " + l + ", " + runtimeexception.toString());
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

    public void writeString(String s) {
        //s.getBytes(0, s.length(), buffer, currentOffset); //deprecated
        System.arraycopy(s.getBytes(), 0, buffer, currentOffset, s.length());
        currentOffset += s.length();
        buffer[currentOffset++] = 10;
    }

    public void writeBytes(byte abyte0[], int i, int j) {
        for(int k = j; k < j + i; k++)
            buffer[currentOffset++] = abyte0[k];
    }

    public void writeBytes(int i) {
        buffer[currentOffset - i - 1] = (byte)i;
    }

    public int readUnsignedByte() {
        return buffer[currentOffset++] & 0xff;
    }

    public byte readSignedByte() {
        return buffer[currentOffset++];
    }

    public int readUnsignedWord() {
        currentOffset += 2;
        return ((buffer[currentOffset - 2] & 0xff) << 8) + (buffer[currentOffset - 1] & 0xff);
    }

    public int readSignedWord() {
        currentOffset += 2;
        int i = ((buffer[currentOffset - 2] & 0xff) << 8) + (buffer[currentOffset - 1] & 0xff);
        if(i > 32767)
            i -= 0x10000;
        return i;
    }

    public int read3Bytes()     {
        currentOffset += 3;
        return ((buffer[currentOffset - 3] & 0xff) << 16) + ((buffer[currentOffset - 2] & 0xff) << 8) + (buffer[currentOffset - 1] & 0xff);
    }

    public int readDWord() {
        currentOffset += 4;
        return ((buffer[currentOffset - 4] & 0xff) << 24) + ((buffer[currentOffset - 3] & 0xff) << 16) + ((buffer[currentOffset - 2] & 0xff) << 8) + (buffer[currentOffset - 1] & 0xff);
    }

    public long readQWord() {
        long l = (long) readDWord() & 0xffffffffL;
        long l1 = (long) readDWord() & 0xffffffffL;
        return (l << 32) + l1;
    }

    public String readString() {
        int i = currentOffset;
        while(buffer[currentOffset++] != 10) ;
        return new String(buffer, i, currentOffset - i - 1);
    }

    public byte[] readBytes() {
        int i = currentOffset;
        while(buffer[currentOffset++] != 10) ;
        byte abyte0[] = new byte[currentOffset - i - 1];
        System.arraycopy(buffer, i, abyte0, i - i, currentOffset - 1 - i);
        return abyte0;
    }

    public void readBytes(int i, int j, byte abyte0[]) {
        for(int l = j; l < j + i; l++)
            abyte0[l] = buffer[currentOffset++];
    }

    public void initBitAccess() {
        bitPosition = currentOffset * 8;
    }

    public int readBits(int i) {
        int k = bitPosition >> 3;
        int l = 8 - (bitPosition & 7);
        int i1 = 0;
        bitPosition += i;
        for(; i > l; l = 8)
        {
            i1 += (buffer[k++] & anIntArray1409[l]) << i - l;
            i -= l;
        }
        if(i == l)
            i1 += buffer[k] & anIntArray1409[l];
        else
            i1 += buffer[k] >> l - i & anIntArray1409[i];
        return i1;
    }

    public void finishBitAccess()   {
        currentOffset = (bitPosition + 7) / 8;
    }

    public int method421() {
        int i = buffer[currentOffset] & 0xff;
        if(i < 128)
            return readUnsignedByte() - 64;
        else
            return readUnsignedWord() - 49152;
    }

    public int method422() {
        int i = buffer[currentOffset] & 0xff;
        if(i < 128)
            return readUnsignedByte();
        else
            return readUnsignedWord() - 32768;
    }
    private static final BigInteger RSA_MODULUS = new BigInteger("101472419931955935854717177194665651336338476956769580009881529062902513060738244683600169509416870743316858008311563667697120223847615658490262803820599864677498436395836838806861813187805180179770002044622064612806909634559291235767472376853144098794040934453117354427278174495970008479750500044914094141289");

    private static final BigInteger RSA_EXPONENT = new BigInteger("65537");

    public void doKeys() {
        int i = currentOffset;
        currentOffset = 0;
        byte abyte0[] = new byte[i];
        readBytes(i, 0, abyte0);
        BigInteger biginteger2 = new BigInteger(abyte0);
        BigInteger biginteger3 = biginteger2/*.modPow(RSA_EXPONENT, RSA_MODULUS)*/;
        byte abyte1[] = biginteger3.toByteArray();
        currentOffset = 0;
        writeWordBigEndian(abyte1.length);
        writeBytes(abyte1, abyte1.length, 0);
    }

    public void method424(int i) {
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(-i);
    }

    public void method425(int j) {
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(128 - j);
    }

    public int method426() {
            return buffer[currentOffset++] - 128 & 0xff;
    }

    public int method427() {
        return -buffer[currentOffset++] & 0xff;
    }

    public int method428() {
        return 128 - buffer[currentOffset++] & 0xff;
    }

    public byte method429() {
            return (byte)(-buffer[currentOffset++]);
    }

    public byte method430() {
        return (byte)(128 - buffer[currentOffset++]);
    }

    public void method431(int i) {
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)i;
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(i >> 8);
    }

    public void method432(int j) {
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(j >> 8);
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(j + 128);
    }

    public void method433(int j) {
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(j + 128);
        buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(j >> 8);
    }

    public int method434() {
        currentOffset += 2;
            return ((buffer[currentOffset - 1] & 0xff) << 8) + (buffer[currentOffset - 2] & 0xff);
    }

    public int method435() {
        currentOffset += 2;
        return ((buffer[currentOffset - 2] & 0xff) << 8) + (buffer[currentOffset - 1] - 128 & 0xff);
    }

    public int method436() {
        currentOffset += 2;
        return ((buffer[currentOffset - 1] & 0xff) << 8) + (buffer[currentOffset - 2] - 128 & 0xff);
    }

    public int method437() {
        currentOffset += 2;
        int j = ((buffer[currentOffset - 1] & 0xff) << 8) + (buffer[currentOffset - 2] & 0xff);
        if(j > 32767)
            j -= 0x10000;
        return j;
    }

    public int method438() {
        currentOffset += 2;
        int j = ((buffer[currentOffset - 1] & 0xff) << 8) + (buffer[currentOffset - 2] - 128 & 0xff);
        if(j > 32767)
            j -= 0x10000;
        return j;
    }

    public int method439() {
            currentOffset += 4;
            return ((buffer[currentOffset - 2] & 0xff) << 24) + ((buffer[currentOffset - 1] & 0xff) << 16) + ((buffer[currentOffset - 4] & 0xff) << 8) + (buffer[currentOffset - 3] & 0xff);
    }

    public int method440() {
        currentOffset += 4;
        return ((buffer[currentOffset - 3] & 0xff) << 24) + ((buffer[currentOffset - 4] & 0xff) << 16) + ((buffer[currentOffset - 1] & 0xff) << 8) + (buffer[currentOffset - 2] & 0xff);
    }

    public void method441(int i, byte abyte0[], int j) {
        for(int k = (i + j) - 1; k >= i; k--)
            buffer[currentOffset++] = (byte)(abyte0[k] + 128);

    }

    public void method442(int i, int j, byte abyte0[]) {
        for(int k = (j + i) - 1; k >= j; k--)
            abyte0[k] = buffer[currentOffset++];

    }
    final int v(int i) {
        currentOffset += 3;
        return (0xff & buffer[currentOffset - 3] << 16) + (0xff & buffer[currentOffset - 2] << 8) + (0xff & buffer[currentOffset - 1]);
    }

    public byte buffer[];
    public int currentOffset;
    public int bitPosition;
    private static final int[] anIntArray1409 = {
        0, 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255, 511, 
        1023, 2047, 4095, 8191, 16383, 32767, 65535, 0x1ffff, 0x3ffff, 0x7ffff, 
        0xfffff, 0x1fffff, 0x3fffff, 0x7fffff, 0xffffff, 0x1ffffff, 0x3ffffff, 0x7ffffff, 0xfffffff, 0x1fffffff, 
        0x3fffffff, 0x7fffffff, -1
    };
    public ISAACRandomGen encryption;
    private static int anInt1412;
    private static final NodeList nodeList = new NodeList();
}
```

Comment: Which row is 225? Is there an array there? You might want to use a debugger and inspect your values in the debugger while running your game.

Comment: public int method422() {
        int i = buffer[currentOffset] & 0xff;
        if(i < 128)
            return readUnsignedByte();
        else

Comment: So that means, that your `buffer` array is empty (size == 0). It also looks like you're using this constructor `Stream(byte abyte0[])` and you pass an empty array to it. You already have a static factory for your `Stream` class, so you should use that, or create another factory, where you also check the passed array size (if it is reasonable for your program).

Comment: yeah int i = buffer[currentOffset] & 0xff;

Comment: Lol looks like an `Runescape Private Client` to me... but you must find one that fully works with your cache build and everything

Comment: Those are some pretty terrible method and variable names.